# Why is my root being set to None?

Tags: python, tree, binary-search-tree

I'm having trouble understanding why my root node is being set to None. Here is a partial of the tree implementation.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, d=None):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = d


class Tree(object):
    root = Node()

    #methods to add data to to the binary search tree
    def add(self, d):
        node_to_add = Node(d)
        if self.root is None: 
            self.root.data = node_to_add
        self._traverse_and_add(self.root, node_to_add)

    def _traverse_and_add(self, node, new_node):
        if new_node.data < node.data:
            if node.left is None:
                node.left = new_node
            else:
                self._traverse_and_add(node.left, new_node)

        elif new_node.data > node.data:
            if node.right is None:
                node.right = new_node
            else:
                self._traverse_and_add(node.right, new_node)
```

When I run the code inside a debugger it shows that my root is None. In my add method I check to see if the root is None and if it is I expect the root.data to take the the value d. After the root has been filled and it not none, then it can add data accordingly.  I use a similar methods in Java I don't have this problem. This bug becomes an issue with later methods, such as finding the depth. Here is a visual of what i'm getting if i use populate the tree

```
t = Tree()
t.add(10)
t.add(2)
t.add(11)


result = 
  None
   /\
  2 10
     \
      11

expected =
   10
   /\
  2 11
```

Comment: You should make `root` in instance variable, otherwise your `Tree` instances will be sharing the same root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set you `root` as `Node()`:

```
class Tree(object):
    root = Node()
```

But here you check it to be `None`:

```
def add(self, d):
    node_to_add = Node(d)
    if self.root is None:  # it is not None, it is Node()
```

Also, you don't have any `__init__` method. You should define your instance variables there.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.root = Node()
```

So, now you can modify you check: `if self.root.data is None`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was an oversight I don't think I would have seen because of the direct translation from java.

Comment: `class Tree(object): root = node()` and `self.Node` are not the same variables, the first one is a static variable of the class, the second is an instance variable.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the lines -

```
if self.root is None: 
    self.root.data = node_to_add
```

In `add()` function you are checking if `root` is none , but you may not even be creating a `root` property inside `self`.

I am guessing you do not have a `__init__` function. You need an `__init__` function with the following code -

```
def __init__(self):
    self.root = None
```

You will need to change the add function as well, as follows -

```
def add(self, d):
    node_to_add = Node(d)
    if self.root is None: 
        self.root = node_to_add
    self._traverse_and_add(self.root, node_to_add)
```

Comment: If `self.root is None`, how can it have a `data` attribute?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that he would have to change add() function a little bit, updating in answer.